# "didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead" in forms.py clean_fieldname() method

Tags: python, django, django-forms, data-cleaning

## Whenever I'm entering special character or any number it should give validation error message but it is showing me "didn't return HttpResponse Error."

ValueError at /events/event/new/
The view events.views.EventCreateView didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

Also this problem is coming when I'm using **nginx**

## forms.py

```
class EventCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ['name', 'date']

    def clean_name(self):
        name = self.cleaned_data['name']
        name = re.sub(' +',' ', name)

        if all(x.isalpha() or x.isspace() for x in name):
            return name
        else:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Please use only alphabets!!!")



#views.py
class EventCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Event
    form_class = EventCreateForm
    template_name = 'events/event_form.html'
```

Comment: `didn't return an HttpResponse object` means you have not mentioned return statement.

Comment: but I don't want to return any HttpResponse instead I want to raise ValidationError check this again

Comment: It is coming whenever I uncomment VALIDATIONERROR line

Comment: Can you please post the stack trace for the error?

Comment: @RaydelMiranda if I do it with django's built-in server, it works fine but when I use nginx then it raises that error

Comment: It seems like you have some `if` in one of your views that performs some sort of checking on` request.path` or some url, And if it fails the condition there is no `return` statement hitten, is the most I can guess.

Comment: hey thanx @RaydelMiranda the problem was in my "url", Thanks

Comment: Any time. I'm happy to help.